# Sum for a column

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT distinct USERID,
case when ACTVCODE = 'POC' then count(ACTVCODE) end POC, 
case when ACTVCODE = 'PIC' then count(ACTVCODE) end PIC, 
case when ACTVCODE = 'EML' then count(ACTVCODE) end EML,
case when ACTVCODE = 'AD' then count(ACTVCODE) end AD, 
case when ACTVCODE = 'LOG' then count(ACTVCODE) end LOG, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'SR' then count(ACTVCODE) end SR, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'DM' then count(ACTVCODE) end DM, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'GK' then count(ACTVCODE) end GK, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'AM' then count(ACTVCODE) end AM, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'NA' then count(ACTVCODE) end NA, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'RO' then count(ACTVCODE) end RO, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'ORE' then count(ACTVCODE) end ORE, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'COM' then count(ACTVCODE) end COM, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'SMS' then count(ACTVCODE) end SMS, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'SV' then count(ACTVCODE) end SV, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'QUO' then count(ACTVCODE) end QUO, 
case when RESULTCODE = 'PQU' then count(ACTVCODE) end PQU
FROM GoldMine.dbo.RESULT_COUNTS RESULT_COUNTS, GoldMine.dbo.USERGRP USERGRP, 
GoldMine.dbo.WT_GMUser WT_GMUser WHERE (RESULT_COUNTS.ONDATE>= '10/3/2017' 
And RESULT_COUNTS.ONDATE<= '10/3/2017') AND 
(RESULT_COUNTS.USERID=WT_GMUser.USERNAME) AND (WT_GMUser.Memberships Like 
'%Corp%') GROUP BY  RESULT_COUNTS.USERID,  RESULT_COUNTS.ACTVCODE, 
RESULT_COUNTS.RESULTCODE
```

here is a sample of the data it produces:

[image: Sample]

I am trying to get where the username only shows up once and there is a sum of the values in the column. I thought using "Distinct" would make the usernames only show up once but it did not work the way I expected it to. My question is what can I add to my sql statement to get one row per USERID and the sum of all the values for each column after.

Let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this in SQL or VB.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for conditional aggregation.  It would look something like this:

```
SELECT rc.USERID,
       sum(case when rc.ACTVCODE = 'POC' then 1 else 0 end) as POC, 
       sum(case when rc.ACTVCODE = 'PIC' then 1 else 0 end) as PIC, 
       . . .
FROM GoldMine.dbo.RESULT_COUNTS rc JOIN
     GoldMine.dbo.WT_GMUser u
     ON rc.USERID = u.USERNAME
WHERE rc.ONDATE >= '2017-10-03' AND
      rc.ONDATE <= '2017-10-03' AND 
      u.Memberships Like '%Corp%'
GROUP BY rc.USERID;
```

Notes:

- You seem to be missing a `JOIN` condition on user groups and the table is not otherwise used in the query.  So I removed that table.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- If you are going to define table aliases make them abbreviations.  The query is easier to write and to read.
- Qualify *all* column names when a query references more than one table.
- Use ISO standard date formats.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the help and suggestions to help my code

Comment: What if I wanted to have a Totals column after column 'LOG' to get the sum of POC through LOG?

Comment: Use `sum(case when rc.actvcode in (. . . ) then 1 else 0 end)`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want one row per `RESULT_COUNTS.USERID`:

```
...
GROUP BY RESULT_COUNTS.USERID;
```

And then one column with the number of rows where `ACTVCODE = 'POC'`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN ACTVCODE = 'POC' THEN 1 END) POC,
```

The `case` expression maps other rows to `null` (due to the implied `else null` clause of `case`). `null` is ignored by `count` so that it only returns the number of rows where `ACTVCODE = 'POC'`.

The same technique can be used for the other columns.

More about this technique: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot